# VM895:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token F in JSON at position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I get this error;

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token F in JSON at position 0
>      at JSON.parse ()
>      at XMLHttpRequest.req.onload (group.html:21)

So I am trying to search for roblox groups that are unowned. So, I first made 2 files.
One is `check.php` (checks if the group is owned, if it is owned, it returns `0` if it isn't owned, it will return the groupid).
The other file is `group.php` (checks if the group has the group funds public, and will try to receive it. If this doesn't work, it will return `Funds Hidden!` otherwise it will just return a number).

Now my problem is when I am trying to make this all wor with a simple page using javascript requests. Here is my code:

```js
function poep (url, id, type) {
   var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
   req.open('GET', url, true); // true = asynchronous
   req.onload = function () {
     var value = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
     if (type == 1) {
      check(value, id);
     } else {
      koef(value, id);
     }
  };
  req.send(null);
}

function search() {
  var from = document.getElementById('from').value;
  var until = document.getElementById('until').value;
  var total = until - from;
  if (total > 100) {
    reload();
  }
  var i;
  for (i = 0; from < until; from++) {
    console.log("checking "+from);
    poep("https://HEREISMYURL/check.php?id="+from, from, 1);
  }
}

function check(value,id) {
  if (value != 0) {
    console.log("UNOWNED output: "+value+ " group id: "+id);
    poep("https://HEREISMYURL/group.php?id="+id, id, 2);
  } else {
    console.log("OWNED output: "+value+ " group id: "+id);
  }
}

function koef(value,id) {
  console.log("FOUND GROUP: "+id+" WITH "+value);
  var before = document.getElementById("results").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = '<a href="https://www.roblox.com/my/groups.aspx?gid='+id+'" target="_blank">Group ID: '+id+ '  Robux AMOUNT: '+value+'</a><br>'+before;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
From (groupid)<br>
<input type="text" id="from"><br><br>
Until (groupid)<br>
<input type="text" id="until"><br>
<button onclick="search()">Search groups</button><br><br><br>
<div id="results"></div>
```

(Sorry for the weird names if you're able to talk in Dutch too. I ran out of names...)

So, I checked the console logs. It first logged all of those `checking...` after that I got a lot of `UNOWNED` and some times `OWNED` inbetween. But then (I guess when checking funds the group has), it will show those errors.

Thanks if you could help me!

Comment: _" If this doesn't work, it will return 'Funds Hidden!'"_ <- ideally it should respond with an unsuccessful response status (ie >= 400) instead of something that is **not** JSON. See [`http_response_code()`](http://php.net/manual/function.http-response-code.php)

Answer (score 2):

`Funds Hidden!` is not JSON.

The error message says:

> Unexpected token F in JSON at position 0

`F` is at position 0 of `Funds Hidden!`.

---

Don't use `JSON.parse` if you aren't parsing JSON!